# HDMI/VGA/DVI: No cable attached within 5 minutes, no signal

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

My situation:

- My pc is connected to my receiver with a hdmi cable
- I start my pc
- 5 minutes later I start the receiver

Problem: No signal. Hitting the keyboard, it doesn't matter, there won't come up any signal. I have to reboot the machine to get the signal. I have seen this behaviour before that if you attach a headless server to a monitor while it's running you don;t get a signal before you reboot.
If I turn on the receiver within 5 minutes, I do get signal..

Some info:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- Graphics card: Asus GT610-SL-1GD3-L (Nvidia)

I'm wondering, how can I change this behaviour.

Best regards,

BHD

Comment: Some video drivers (intel for one) detect if you change the monitor configuration on the fly, some I guess don't. What video card do you have?

Comment: I have the Asus GT610-SL-1GD3-L from nvidia